# Saturation-like effect of the atmosphere on sunlight?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, atmospheric-science

Does the atmosphere have any kind of saturation effect whereby the intensity of the light hitting the surface of the earth is non-linearly proportional to the output of the sun? In other words, is there a point where there's an extra level of absorbance present in the atmosphere due to it already containing a high amount of light scattering around, and it starts becoming opaque?

If so, is the size of this effect noticeable for the regular output of the sun, or would we need some massive luminosity before it becomes significant?

The question came to mind when a friend asked during the solar eclipse if there's a linear difference in brightness when the sun is partially obscured by the moon, such that a 20% occlusion would mean we're receiving roughly 80% of the regular amount of light we would normally (ignoring effects like refraction and so on).

Comment: In a word, yes - but only in some spectral bands.

Comment: When you say *light*, do you mean visible light, do you include UV and IR, or do you include any electromagnetic radiation?

Comment: @gerrit Any radiation; particularly what the sun is producing, but I am interested in the difference across the spectrum.

Comment: Can't edit my previous comment, but when I said what the sun is producing, I meant the proportion of that which normally hits the surface of the earth.